# Regex capture group is not capturing data

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture any alpha numeric character between `''`
[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/oE9Wo5/2)

```
'(.*.doc)' will only capture .doc files.
'(\w)' should capture any alpha numeric character.
```

But I am looking to capture any character between `''` except the `----` characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use the following regular expression: `([^\-\[\][\n']+)`

An example:
[regexr.com/5btcs](http://regexr.com/5btcs)

Comment: thanks.  `'([^\-\[\][\n']+)'` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is this good?

`'[^'-]*'`

Means a single `'`, then anything not `'` or `-`, then another `'`.

If you wish to capture things around the dashes though, you might have to capture inclusively and filter them out.